# HTML Edit preview in vertical landscape in Komodo Edit

Tags: komodo

I'm trying out different text editor for HTML coding. I want an editor with a preview mode instead of having to open it in a browser every time. I have tried Atom but my preview package is acting bugging and only moves left but cannot move to the right.

I found out that Komodo Edit 11.1 does a preview but right now it is only showing it in a horizontal preview. How do I make a vertical preview as shown below? *(This is from W3Schools.com)*

[image]

Here is what my Komodo Editor looks like now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. To my own question. If you guys are looking for the same thing. Here is what you do.

1. **Right-click** at the top of the editor and click on **"Show Menubar"**

[image]

2. **Hover your mouse** over **View** and navigate down to **"Rotate Split View"**

[image]